# Get Maximum Common String in C++?

Tags: c++, string, function, substring

I have 2 strings:

"abcdef" and "123abcdef123"

I am looking for a function that gets these 2 strings as parameter and returns the biggest common string. So in this case it should return "abcdef".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem

Comment: Have you tried google maybe? https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=c%2B%2B%20find%20longest%20common%20string

Comment: We will not do your homework here. Show us some effort first.

Comment: Find system function can help you -> http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html

Comment: http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/algorithm-alley/184404588

Comment: Found it:
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/56770-longest-common-substring/

Comment: Thank you all for the responses !

Answer (score -1):

Answer:

string common (string first, string second) {

```
string lcsub, max;

for (unsigned int i=0; i < first.length(); i++)

    for (unsigned int j=0; j < second.length(); j++)

        for (unsigned int k=1; k <= first.length() && k <= second.length(); k++){

            if (first.substr(i,k) == second.substr(j,k)){

                lcsub = first.substr(i,k);

            }

            else{

                if (lcsub.length() > max.length())

                    max=lcsub;

                lcsub="";

            }

        }

if (lcsub.length() > max.length())

    max=lcsub;

lcsub="";

cout << "Longest Common Substring: " << max << endl;
return max;
```

}